# ASP .net framework client with identityserver4 authentication couldn't access to unauthorize sections after login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, identityserver4, .net-4.8

I implemented an SSO with IdentityServer4 and 3 clients. two of clients, are `ASP.NET Core`
and other is `ASP.net Framework`.

Both .Net Core clients, work well. but the problem is in .Net Framework client. after Login, when user navigate to unauthorized path and section, browser Redirect it to `"/signin-oidc"` (but in .Net Core clients, it doesn't happen) (also user login successfully, because it doesn't redirect client to Login page anymore and in two other projects, user logged in).

Whate is problem? These are my code:

**Config in SSO project:**

```
 public class Config
    {
        ...

        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>()
            {
                new Client()
                {
                    ClientId = "SSO_Client",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RedirectUris = {
                        "https://localhost:44387/signin-oidc",  //.Net Core Client
                        "https://localhost:44382/signin-oidc",  //.Net Core Client
                        "https://localhost:44385/signin-oidc"   //.Net Framework 
                    },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = {
                        "https://localhost:44387/signout-callback-oidc",  //.Net Core Client
                        "https://localhost:44382/signout-callback-oidc",  //.Net Core Client
                        "https://localhost:44385/signout-callback-oidc"   //.Net Framework Client
                    },
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>()
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        "organ",
                        "access-control"
                    },
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

**Startup In .Net framework project:**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "https://localhost:44372",  //SSO Project
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

                ClientId = "SSO_Client",
                ClientSecret = "secret",
                ResponseType = "code",

                SaveTokens = true,

                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44385/signin-oidc",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44385/signout-callback-oidc", 

                Scope = "openid profile email organ",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Right now you have only one client in your configuration method. Configure another(second) [IdentityServer4 client](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/clients.html#defining-clients) if you need it

Comment: @AndrewSilver Thanks. but that is correct. because I want one authentication and cookie for these three application and it works well.

Comment: @AndrewSilver is right, you should have diferent clients. You will have one SSO Cookie issued by you Authority and one Cookie session for every client. You don't need the same client to get SSO. And every client may need diferents allowed scopes, allowed grants...